House alarm triggers once power restored after power cut
I have Optima xm alarm system fitted. I recently had external bell sounder replaced by local alarm company. Prior to this I replaced the internal battery with correct spec new one. We had some power cuts last week and after power is restored alarm triggers. I suspected it might be a faulty replacement battery but checked it over with megger and it was fine. I checked 2 fuses fitted and they're also fine. I tried another battery but as before if you turn off mains  then turn on the alarm sounds. My wife then said it always did this from when we had it installed when we bought our house. I've seen som others with this system have similar issue but no resolution so wondering what else to check.

Ask the company that makes it if it is a feature or a defect.

That is standard behavior for many alarm systems. Typically, on power restore you need to press a key sequence at the controller, or a reset button, or some such, within a certain (short) time period.
